# Method defined in class not found in Generic class (Java)

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am trying to create an ArrayList class in Java, as a homework assignment. We have been given a most of the method outlines, and left up to us to implement. One of the methods is to enlarge a generic list if the current size of the list cannot support adding an additional element (up to a certain size). Yet, everytime I try to compile the following it gives me an error that .enlarge is not recognized. Here is the declaration of the list and the constructors

```
public class ArrayList<E extends Comparable<E>> {
private final int DEFCAP = 50;
private int origCap;
private int numElements;
private Object[] list;

/*  Method Name      : ArrayList()
    Parameters       : None
    Return value(s)  : Constructor
    Partners         : None
    Description      : Increase the sales of the Employee at the given index by the given double amount.
*/
public ArrayList() {
    origCap = DEFCAP;
    numElements = 0;
    list = (E[]) new Object[DEFCAP];
}

/*  Method Name      : ArrayList()
    Parameters       : int size
    Return value(s)  : Constructor
    Partners         : None
    Description      : Increase the sales of the Employee at the given index by the given double amount.
*/
public ArrayList(int size) {
    try {
        if(size > DEFCAP || size < 1) {
            throw new InvalidSizeException();
        }
        origCap = size;
        numElements = 0;
        list = (E[]) new Object[origCap];
    } catch (InvalidSizeException ISE) {
        System.err.println("Size too large");
    }
}
```

Here is the method that calls the enlarge:

```
    public void addItem(E item) throws MaximumCapacityException {
    try {
        if((numElements + 1 ) >= DEFCAP) {
            throw new MaximumCapacityException();
        } else if (numElements >= origCap && numElements < DEFCAP) {
            list.enlarge();
            list[numElements - 1] = item;
            numElements++;
        } else {
            list[numElements - 1] = item;
            numElements++;
        }

    } catch (MaxiumumCapacityException MCE) {
        System.err.println("List at maximum capacity");
    }
}
```

And here is the enlarge method itself:

```
    private void enlarge() throws MaximumCapacityException {
    try {
        if(list.length() == DEFCAP) {
            throw new MaximumCapacityException();
        } else if((list.length() + origCap > DEFCAP) && list.length() <= DEFCAP) {
            Object[] newlist = (E[]) Object[DEFCAP];
            for(int i = 0; i < numElements;i++) {
                newlist[i] = list[i];
            }
            list = newlist;
        } else {
            Object[] newlist = (E[]) Object[DEFCAP];
            for(int i = 0; i < numElements;i++) {
                newlist[i] = list[i];
            }
            list = newlist;
        }
    } catch(MaxiumumCapacityException MCE) {
        System.err.println("Size too large");
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
ArrayList.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
            list.enlarge();
                ^
```

symbol:   method enlarge()
  location: variable list of type Object[]

I am bashing my head against a wall on this question. It's for a homework assignment, but I can't for the life of me figure out why its not compiling. If I understand the error correctly, it means that the compiler still thinks that *list* is of the type Object. Shouldn't it have changed when it was casted to an E[] in the constructor? Or does that just change the elements of the array?

Any help would be appreciated. If there are other errors, feel free to point them out, but I figure I can start tackling those once I figure this out.

Comment: casting doesn't change the type of object unless you assign the result to that object (of the type that you cast to).

Comment: `list.enlarge()` means "call the `enlarge()` method provided by `list`. `list` is an array. It does not provide such a method.

Comment: ``list`` is an ``Object[]`` and has no method ``enlarge()``.  Maybe the element of the array are the ones that have that method?  Is there supposed to be an ``enlarge`` method on ``ArrayList``?  BTW, I would name it something other than ``ArrayList`` as there is already a Java class of that name.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the class name, it needs to be this for the assignment (aka creating our own version of ArrayList).

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues:

- list.length() should be list.length
- list.enlarge() should be this.enlarge()
- Object[] newlist = (E[]) Object[DEFCAP]; should be Object[] newlist = new Object[DEFCAP];

UPDATED

This is my code version, no compilation errors

```
package a;

public class ArrayList<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private final int DEFCAP = 50;
    private int origCap;
    private int numElements;
    private E[] list;

    /*
     * Method Name : ArrayList() Parameters : None Return value(s) : Constructor Partners : None Description : Increase
     * the sales of the Employee at the given index by the given double amount.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayList() {
        origCap = DEFCAP;
        numElements = 0;
        list = (E[]) new Object[DEFCAP];
    }

    /*
     * Method Name : ArrayList() Parameters : int size Return value(s) : Constructor Partners : None Description :
     * Increase the sales of the Employee at the given index by the given double amount.
     */
    public ArrayList(int size) {
        try {
            if (size > DEFCAP || size < 1) {
                throw new InvalidSizeException();
            }
            origCap = size;
            numElements = 0;
            list = (E[]) new Object[origCap];
        } catch (InvalidSizeException ISE) {
            System.err.println("Size too large");
        }
    }

    // Here is the method that calls the enlarge:

    public void addItem(E item) throws MaximumCapacityException {
        if ((numElements + 1) >= DEFCAP) {
            throw new MaximumCapacityException();
        } else if (numElements >= origCap && numElements < DEFCAP) {
            enlarge();
            list[numElements - 1] = item;
            numElements++;
        } else {
            list[numElements - 1] = item;
            numElements++;
        }
    }

    private void enlarge() throws MaximumCapacityException {
        if (list.length == DEFCAP) {
            throw new MaximumCapacityException();
        } else if ((list.length + origCap > DEFCAP) && list.length <= DEFCAP) {
            E[] newlist = (E[]) new Object[DEFCAP];
            for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
                newlist[i] = list[i];
            }
            list = newlist;
        } else {
            E[] newlist = (E[]) new Object[DEFCAP];
            for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
                newlist[i] = list[i];
            }
            list = newlist;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On your last point - would I not want to create the newlist as a casted E() like I did in the constructor? Or is that not neccessary, since its copying over items already created?

Comment: let me see it, give me a second

Comment: Yes, you ca do it with Object[] newlist = (E[]) new Object[DEFCAP]; You may want to define your Object[] list as E[] list, so it would be like this E[] newlist = (E[]) new Object[DEFCAP]; and the member list too

Comment: Doing it that way gives me another error:
    ArrayList.java:212: error: cannot find symbol
                E[] newlist = (E[]) Object[DEFCAP];
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable Object
  location: class ArrayList<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Comparable<E> declared in class ArrayList

Comment: I updated the question with code, no compilation errors. Note i delete some excepcion try blocks because I don´t have exception classes used in your code

Answer (score 1):

You have two concepts here:

- The `ArrayList` class that you are implementing
- The `list` object array which is a field of your `Arraylist` and is what the ArrayList uses internally to hold its data.

You don't `enlarge` the internal data. `enlarge` is behaviour you've defined on your ArrayList. The body of the `enlarge` method does the work of *enlarging* the internal array. So as mentioned in [Francisco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33613343/926710), your call to `enlarge` should be a `this.enlarge()` statement (or just `enlarge()`).

```
...
else if (numElements >= origCap && numElements < DEFCAP) {
  this.enlarge(); // not list.enlarge()
  list[numElements - 1] = item;
  numElements++;
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. both of those changes removed those errors. Now on to the other 13 I have in the program.